# Server side validation - Login with Facebook without Redirection

Tags: node.js, angular, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I was implementing [Angular 9 Social Login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-social-login) in my `frontend` application.

---

**(for those who are not familiar with `angular-social-login`:**

## Front end process:

1. Opens a new `browser tab`
2. Ask to permit access to the user's public profile.
3. provide a `response` with the `auth token` of the user login.

---

## Target:

Now I want to take the token which the user received, send it to the server (`node.js`) and there communicating with `Facebook` in order to verify this `auth token` and fetch the user's profile data.

---

## Attempts:

I've tried to use [Facebook manually login flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2) and **Confirming Identity** section.

There I found this endpoint to generate an `access token` (what's for? I either can not understand):

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/oauth/access_token?
   client_id={app-id}
   &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
   &client_secret={app-secret}
   &code={code-parameter}
```

---

## Questions:

1. Which `API endpoint` should be used in order to "provide `token` and fetch `profile`" from facebook?
2. Do I need to generate this `access token` with the above `endpoint`? If yes - Why do I need to provide this `redirect_uri` param?

Comment: That endpoint is for exchanging a `code` parameter you get back from the login flow, for a token. This is something you should do on the server side to begin with – your client secret must never be exposed in client-side code. And the redirect_uri parameter serves the purpose of redirecting the user back to your application _from_ the Facebook login dialog.

Comment: You can also handle that part purely client-side, by specifying that you want to receive a token directly, via the `response_type` parameter in the login dialog call URL. (But in this case, I see no real advantage in doing tha, you might as well handle this on the server side to begin with. This option is rather for _purely_ client-side apps.)

Comment: The `angular social package` is opening a new dialog and than close it. After then, I have a callback (subscription) with the auth token the user received. I dont need to redirect him to my app as he never go away....

Comment: Then I don’t get what your question actually is. If you already have an access token - then you can obviously skip the part titled “Exchanging Code for an Access Token”, which is exactly the endpoint you mentioned above. Either proceed with “Inspecting Access Tokens” then, if you want to validate the token you passed to the server … or just use it to start making your API calls. (If the token was not valid, you would get an according response then.)

Comment: @CBROE I got this in the frontend: https://imgur.com/a/4YkES53
Now I want to verify in front of facebook that the details are correct and that the user hasnt manipulated them

Comment: What’s “verify in front of facebook” supposed to mean? Verifying anything on the client side, makes rather little sense to begin with here - if I can fake the data, then I will likely be able to fake the result of your client-side verification as well. If you are concerned about eventually inserting this data into a server-side database - then _request_ it via a server-side API call to begin with. (The only thing you’d be trusting then, that comes directly from the client, would be the access token.)

Comment: @CBroe. Thats exactly what I meant. How can I request the data from my server side with that auth token? What is the endpoint I should use?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/common-scenarios#get-data-about-me-or-others - you can use `/me` for the path, that will automatically resolve to the user the token belongs to. And you will need to specifically ask for the fields you want using the `fields` parameter.